# Optimal Edge Weights

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

There is a state (territory) which is a tree rooted at node 1. All the cities (numbered from 1 to N+1) 
in this state are connected via bidirectional roads. You have to add toll tax on each road. There are N roads which connect the cities of the state. You have to assign toll taxes on the roads so as to maximize the function Toll described below:

```
for(i=1;i<=number of cities;i++)
{
    for(j=i+1;j<=number of cities;j++)
    {
        toll+=(toll required to pay to travel from i to j)
     } 
}
```

You have to maximize the toll tax. Assign the roads by toll taxes from the given array A(using each value exactly once). Find the maximum toll obtained.

**Input Format:**

First line contains

> N and an integer whose value is always 2.

Then,

> N roads follow containing 2 integers u and v, denoting the cities
>   between which the road is.

Next line contains N space separated values denoting elements of array A.

**Output Format**

Print the maximum toll which can be obtained.

Input Constraints

```
1≤N≤2∗10^5

1≤A[i]≤1000
1≤u,v≤N+1
```

**Sample Input**

```
2 2

1 3

2 3

5 7
```

**Sample Output**

```
24
```

**Explanation**
Assign 5 to edge (1- 3) and 7 to edge (2 - 3). This leads to an maximum toll tax of 24.

Comment: Sample Input Is Like This
2 2
1 3
2 3
5 7

Comment: Do  you have a question?  Or are you trying to hire someone to do your homework?

Comment: AnyWay, I scratched my head lot of times to solve this. Thought of putting it publically to get a solution.@dawood ibn kareem

Comment: Yeah, that's not really how this site works.  If you can ask a specific question, you might get a good answer on this site.  But dumping a bunch of requirements and hoping someone will write code for you is almost certain to lead to disappointment.

Answer (score 0):

First, when you look at your `Toll` function code and Sample Input, then you'll see that this function counts just paths:

- from 1 to 3
- from 2 to 3
- but not 3 to 1
- and not 3 to 2,

because `j` is always more than `i`, so this leads us that 24 is incorrect answer (or you have incorrect `Toll`) function.

Second, according to the task (but I believe it just was described wrong) the answer will be always equal to sum of elements from array A, because the task sounds like : put elements to a symmetric matrix and then calculate a sum above (or below) a diagonal, but it is going to be all of the same elements from array A.

Answer (score 0):

**The Question you asked belongs to Graph.**

Three cities are given from 1 -> 3. If you randomly assign values from A[] and use that in the toll function you will get the following output:

Assume you assigned 5 to Edge 1-3, and 7 to edge 2-3, 
The graph would be like 1------3------2

Then According to the toll function, you will get the following routes:

1-2  === 7 + 5 = 12

1-3  === 5

2-3 ===  7

So , the total toll would be = 12+5+7 = 24.

**Hence, you need to first construct the graph . then assign the tolls randomly and find toll money for all the possible combinations.
or else, 
you can use concept of Minimum Spanning Tree for Graph. You just need to inverse the use of kruskal or Prim's algorithm to find a route with maximum toll**

PS: The meaning of bi-directional road is that suppose your first for loop starts from 3 and second for loop starts from 1, then you can also go 3->1 whose toll would be same as you used before for 1->3.

Hope this helps. :)